# App Store Screenshots uploading 4,7-inch instead of 5.5-inch

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am planning to submit iOS app on the App Store and my app only supports devices that has eSIM capability. Since none of 5.5-inch devices support eSIM, and since iPhone SE 2 is supported, I was wondering if it's okay if I upload 4.7-inch screenshots instead of 5.5-inch. (Of course, I will upload 6.5-inch screenshots)

From the screenshot specifications from Apple, wordings seems little too vague for me to understand. https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

- 5.5 inch (iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus) **Required if app runs on iPhone**
- 4.7 inch (iPhone SE (2nd generation), iPhone 8, iPhone 7, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6) **Required if app runs on iPhone and 5.5-inch screenshots are not provided**

Does this mean 4.7-inch can be replaced since 5.5-inch screenshots are **not provided**? Or does it mean I MUST upload 5.5-inch screenshots since it's **Required**?

Comment: the 6.5" and 5.5" screenshots need to be uploaded, some of the other sizes will downscale and inherit from these images for iPhone; you need to provide these two key sizes because those are the largest sizes of that particular screen ratio.

Comment: the info under the link you provided is very clear about that: __6.5" = must have;__ 5.8" = if not provided, it will inherit from 6.5"; __5.5" = must have;__ 4.7" & 4" & 3.5" = if not provided, it will inherit from 5.5" – if that explanation makes it more clear.